# Batch File to Determine the Minimum of a String of Data in Another File

Tags: batch-file, minimum

I have a CSV file with a column of data (of variable length)--call this file data.csv. I need a batch file that will read in data.csv and output the minimum of its data to another file, say min.csv.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does "output the minimum of its data" mean?  [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?  Please modify your question and ask it [the smart way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: rojo, thanks for the constructive criticism (said with sarcasm). As I stated, I have a csv file containing a column of numerical data. I need a batch file that will read in this csv file and scroll through its contents (i.e. evaluating the numerical data) and then compute the minimum. This minimum should then be written to another file.

Paul Safier

Comment: @PaulSafier  `compute the minimum` is very vague and broad.  Do you mean just display the smallest value?  Or is there some sort of formulaic equation that needs to be performed?

Comment: David: Correct, the smallest value (aka the minimum) should be displayed, or better yet, sent to a file. For example, if the data file (e.g. data.csv) contains the numbers "1.4,5,2,3.9,8,67,21,22.6" then the batch file would determine the minimum to be 1.4 and then output 1.4 to a file (call it min.csv). Does that help clarify? -Paul Safier

Comment: How many columns? Which column has the number? What is the maximum possible absolute value? Can any columns be empty? The problem can be solved with batch, but it is not simple, and will be relatively slow. The problem is much easier to solve using PowerShell.

Comment: dbenham: there is just a single column of numbers. No rows will be empty. No number will be larger than 7 digits including the decimal point, for example: XXXX.XX. Thanks! -Paul Safier

Comment: @PaulSafier - My criticism was indeed intended to be constructive.  The tone of your original question implies that you consider yourself to be entitled to have us write exactly what you need from scratch.  That's not what we're here for.  I don't expect that you'll read the entire essay on "How to ask questions the smart way", but at least read the [introduction](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#intro).  IMHO, you need that more urgently than you need code to sort a **row** (not a column) of csv data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

After answering the question, I read some of the comments below your question and I conclude that you intended to say "I have a csv file with a *row* of data" in stead of "I have a csv file with a *column* of data". In the case of a row of data, batch files are very limited and clumsy to use. See [this link](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) for an overview and draw your conclusion that you should probably look for a different solution than using a batch file.

---

The algorithm is simple, the problem is the syntax of batch. The following works for me:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET minval=2147483647

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (data.csv) DO (
    IF !minval! GTR %%A SET minval=%%A
REM    ECHO A is %%A and minval is !minval!
)
ECHO !minval!
```

Un-`REM` the `ECHO` to see intermediate results.

Input example:

```
1000000
1000
10000
1
-15
100
```

Result, with `ECHO` active:

```
A is 1000000 and minval is 1000000
A is 1000 and minval is 1000
A is 10000 and minval is 1000
A is 1 and minval is 1
A is -15 and minval is -15
A is 100 and minval is -15
-15
```

If you want to write the result to a file, just run it as `findmin.bat > min.csv` (assuming the name of the batch-file is `findmin.bat`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Turns out I also found a solution, namely I coded the minimum determination in FORTRAN and just had the batch file call that excecutable. -Paul Safier

Comment: You are welcome, good to hear you found a better solution. Batch programming is not nearly as much fun as FORTRAN ;-)